# Embedded PDF - open page number without reloading the document

Tags: javascript, pdf

I have embedded a PDF document using the html object tag, and displayed it on one section of the webpage. Another section contains a tree-view of links (looks like the PDF's bookmarks).  Clicking on a link in the tree-view reloads the PDF document and opens it on the correct page (page number is contained in the links). 
Is there a way to accomplish this without reloading the document?

To rephrase the question, I am looking for a JavaScript function that could imitate the behavior of the bookmarks - jumping to the page number without reloading the document.

Answer (score 7):

I think there is no native method in JavaScript that would provide that functionality. You are going to need a library.

The easiest way would be to use a well documented library to work with pdf documents in JavaScript. **[PDF.js](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js)** is a very good project in that sense, although it renders the pdf itself, instead of using Acrobat Reader, which might give problems with complicated documents.

---

Another solution, using **Adobe Acrobat** reader, would be to use their own [JavaScript API](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/js_api_reference.pdf), following that link you will see the complete API reference. Quoting from that document (Page 254):

> **pageNum**
>
> Gets or sets the current page of the document. When setting pageNum to a specific page, remember that 
>   the values are 0-based. [...]

So if you wanted to go to a specific page of the document you could use

```
this.pageNum = 6;
```

Where *this* should be the app context. Here you can find the [online API reference](http://livedocs.adobe.com/acrobat_sdk/10/Acrobat10_HTMLHelp/wwhelp/wwhimpl/js/html/wwhelp.htm?href=JavaScript_SectionPage.70.1.html#1515775&accessible=true) with more documentation and examples.

Some guides on using the above JS API:

- http://blogs.adobe.com/pdfdevjunkie/web_designers_guide
- http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_Passing_information_actions_from_the_browser_to_an-18885.html
- http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_open_parameters_v9.pdf#page=5

Comment: can you interact w/ an embedded pdf document in this way using javascript in the enclosing webpage?

Comment: Indeed, I have updated my answer with more guides on the subject